# Import Static 3rd-Party (SDL2) Library in CMake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sdl

I am trying to start a project using CMake (3.5.2). For my project, I want to use SDL2. This is the folder hierarchy so far.

```
PROJECT
├── Applications
├── External
│   └── SDL2
├── Games
├── Libraries
│   └── Rendering
└── Tests
    └── Testen
```

The Rendering Library I'm working on has a dependency on SDL2 and Testen has a dependency on SDL2. I built SDL2 as a static library for each platform and before I attempted to import SDL2 to my CMake project, I had a console based test application in a working state. After attempting to add it, I got stumped on...

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target /**FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIR**/External/SDL2/SDL2-2.0.5/Xcode/SDL/Build/libSDL2.a, needed by `Tests/Testen/Testen.app/Contents/MacOS/Testen'.  Stop.
```

Here is the CMake list for SDL2

```
SET (SDL2_NAME "External::SDL2")
SET (SDL2_LIBRARY "***ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_LIBRARY***")
SET (SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR "***ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_LIBRARY_DIR***")
SET (SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR "***ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SDL2_INCLUDES***")

LINK_DIRECTORIES( "${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR}" )

ADD_LIBRARY ( 
    ${SDL2_NAME}

    STATIC
    IMPORTED
    GLOBAL
)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (
    ${SDL2_NAME}

    PROPERTIES

    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
    LINK_DIRECTORIES ${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR}
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
```

Here is the CMake list for the rendering wrapper library

```
SET ( LIBRARY_NAME Rendering)

SET (   
    HEADERS

    Header1.h
    Header2.h
    Header3.h
    Header4.h
)


SET (   
    SOURCE

    Source1.cpp
    Source2.cpp
    Source3.cpp
    Source4.cpp
)


SET (
    LIB_DEPENDENCIES

    SomeOtherLibraryWrittenByMe
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES( "${***ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR***}" )

ADD_LIBRARY (
    ${LIBRARY_NAME}

    ${SOURCE}
    ${HEADERS}
)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES (
    ${LIBRARY_NAME}

    ${LIB_DEPENDENCIES}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (
    ${LIBRARY_NAME}

    ${LIB_DEPENDENCIES}
    External::SDL2
)
```

Here is the CMake list for Testen (my test application)

```
SET ( APP_NAME Testen)
SET ( APP_HEADERS ***SAME_STYLE_AS_RENDERING***)
SET ( APP_SOURCE ***SAME_STYLE_AS_RENDERING***)

LINK_DIRECTORIES( "${***ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SDL2_LIBRARY_DIR***}" )

# Here we put together our executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( 
    ${APP_NAME}

    MACOSX_BUNDLE # Because I'm on a mac right now

    ${APP_HEADERS}
    ${APP_SOURCE}
)


ADD_DEPENDENCIES ( 
    ${APP_NAME}

    Rendering
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (
    ${APP_NAME}

    Rendering
)
```

The goal of my project is to understand more about different aspects of programming. That said, I am actively avoiding using helper scripts like [FindSDL2.cmake](https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts) and other such modules. Perhaps that may be the tool I need to solve my problem, but I'd like to know exactly what it's doing so if I ever attempt to add something to my project that DOESN'T have a Find.cmake script, I'm not blocked.

Comment: Path in the error message is the one you assign for *IMPORTED_LOCATION* for SDL2 library. If you want to link your library with SDL2 and than remove SDL2 one, make this linking as *PRIVATE*, so it will be not propagated to executable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've changed the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES in the Rendering library to privately link SDL2 but all that seemed to do was move the error from Testen to Rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to say that my issue was the result of a typo in the libSDL2.a path. Though, @Tsyvarev did bring up a good point that I should be linking SDL2 as PRIVATE. I'm currently trying to solve linker errors now in SDL2 related to function calls within the library to MACOSX framework functions. I may post a question about that too though I will try to debug this for a while.

Thanks to everyone who thought about this!
Special thanks to @Tsyvarev :)

*edit* - I solved the linker errors by linking the frameworks against my executable. Everything is back to how it was